# how to stop process if images are loaded in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to display images in JFrame. They are printing well without any problem. But when I close the JFrame window, the process is still running even the window is closed. How can I stop the image loading thread? Please explain with example coding.

Comment: At a bare minimum, show your code.

Comment: You've omitted very important information in the above, and you've been told that by three people (so far). Edit the question to add the necessary information (*don't* create a new, separate question like you did a moment ago). Barring that, eventually the community will have to close and delete this question as "not a real question."

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
youJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

or you can do it programmatically with:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Or:

```
youJFrame.dispose(); // this will end the program if no other threads are running.
```

---

**EDIT:**

> how to stop the image loading thread

You can send it a signal with `interrupt()` method.

Comment: thanks for the response. but in my program my first jframe window links with other lframe window. when i press a button present window should disapper and new window appears. its working but if i close my second window, the process belonging to first window is still running

Comment: @user1415043 for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) otherwise everything are shots to the dark

Answer (score 3):

You probably haven't set default close operation for the JFrame. Not sure which you want but it's probably that the application should close when the window closes. If so,

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

if your JFrame is called `frame`. If you just want to release any resources taken up by the JFrame use JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE instead.

Comment: thanks for the response. but in my program my first jframe window links with other lframe window. when i press a button present window should disapper and new window appears. its working but if i close my second window, the process belonging to first window is still running

Comment: As others have pointed out, please show your code. What is the code triggered when pressing the button, e.g. how do you make present window "disappear"?